# How to create LV

Tags: rhel, lvm

I want to create some LV in my VG

**I have this:**

> LV Name                /dev/vg_appli/lv_grt
>   LV Size                  10,00 GB
>
> LV Name                /dev/vg_appli/lv_sap 
>    LV Size                  7,00 GB
>
> LV Name                /dev/vg_appli/lv_PRC
>   LV Size                  15,00 GB
>
> LV Name                /dev/vg_appli/lv_archDCM
>   LV Size                  20,00 GB

**I create like this:**

```
fdisk -l    
pvcreate /dev/sdc   
vgcreate vg_appli /dev/sdc  
lvcreate -l **?** vg_appli -n lv_grt    
lvcreate -l **?** vg_appli -n lv_sap    
lvcreate -l **?** vg_appli -n lv_PRC    
lvcreate -l **?** vg_appli -n lv_archDCM

lvdisplay /dev/vg_appli         
mkfs.ext3 -m 0 /dev/vg_appli/lv_grt     
mkfs.ext3 -m 0 /dev/vg_appli/lv_sap     
mkfs.ext3 -m 0 /dev/vg_appli/lv_PRC     
mkfs.ext3 -m 0 /dev/vg_appli/lv_archDCM
```

I do not know what to put in place of **'?'**

Comment: You got to use the uppercase 'L' to specify size in B/kB/mB/gB/etc. Ask your console `lvcreate --help` to view the current exact notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to set it up. If you use the `-l` switch then you're specifying it in terms of the logical extents. If you use the switch `-L` you can specify it in terms of size (any thing with a unit after it should do - 150GB - for example).

```
-l, --extents LogicalExtentsNumber[%{VG|PVS|FREE|ORIGIN}]
        Gives  the  number  of logical extents to allocate for the new 
        logical volume.  The number can also be expressed as a percentage
        of the total space in the Volume Group with the suffix %VG, as a
        percentage of the remaining free space in the Volume Group with 
        the suffix %FREE, as a percentage of the remaining free space for 
        the  specified PhysicalVolume(s) with the suffix %PVS, or (for
        a snapshot) as a percentage of the total space in the Origin 
        Logical Volume with the suffix %ORIGIN.

-L, --size LogicalVolumeSize[bBsSkKmMgGtTpPeE]
        Gives  the  size to allocate for the new logical volume.  A size 
        suffix of K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for gigabytes, T for 
        terabytes, P for petabytes or E for exabytes is optional.
        Default unit is megabytes.
```

#### What are extents?

Yes these confused me when I first setup LVM on my RAID too. I always refer to this source to refresh my memory:

*excerpt from [Unix/Linux Administration Logical Volume Management Guide](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/LVM.htm)*

> Extents:
>
> When creating a volume group from one or more physical volumes, you
>   must specify the size of the "extents" of each of the physical volumes
>   that make up the VG.  Each extent is a single contiguous chunk of disk
>   space, typically 4M in size, but can range from 8K to 16G in powers of
>   2 only.  (Extents are analogous to disk blocks or clusters.)  The
>   significance of this is that the size of logical volumes are specified
>   as a number of extents.  Logical volumes can thus grow and shrink in
>   increments of the extent size.  A volume group's extent size cannot be
>   changed after it is set.
>
> The system internally numbers the extents for both logical and
>   physical volumes.  These are called logical extents (or LEs) and
>   physical extents (or PEs), respectively.  When a logical volume is
>   created a mapping is defined between logical extents (which are
>   logically numbered sequentially starting at zero) and physical extents
>   (which are also numbered sequentially).
>
> To provide acceptable performance the extent size must be a multiple
>   of the actual disk cluster size (i.e., the size of the smallest chunk
>   of data that can be accessed in a single disk I/O operation).  In
>   addition some applications (such as Oracle database) have performance
>   that is very sensitive to the extent size.  So setting this correctly
>   also depends on what the storage will be used for, and is considered
>   part of the system administrator's job of tuning the system.

That explains what they are. I use this article to figure out how to calculate them:

*excerpt from [Managing RAID and LVM with Linux (v0.5)](http://www.gagme.com/greg/linux/raid-lvm.php)*

> The default value for the physical extent size can be too low for a
>   large RAID array. In those cases you'll need to specify the -s option
>   with a larger than default physical extent size. The default is only
>   4MB as of the version in Fedora Core 5. The maximum number of physical
>   extents is approximately 65k so take your maximum volume size and
>   divide it by 65k then round it to the next nice round number. For
>   example, to successfully create a 550G RAID let's figure that's
>   approximately 550,000 megabytes and divide by 65,000 which gives you
>   roughly 8.46. Round it up to the next nice round number and use 16M
>   (for 16 megabytes) as the physical extent size and you'll be fine:
>
> ```
>  # vgcreate -s 16M <volume group name>
> ```

So with that above command you've created the empty volume group. You can query it to see how many Physical Extents (PEs) are available.

You can then use the `vgdisplay` command to see the actual number of PEs:

```
$ vgdisplay lvm-raid
    .
    .
   Free  PE / Size       57235 / 223.57 GB
```

If you want to assign them all to your logical volume, you do the following:

```
$ lvcreate -l 57235 lvm-raid -n lvm0
```

You can then comfirm using `lvdisplay`. Not the path is a concatenation of the logical volume (lvm-raid) and the logical volume (lvm0), mainly `/dev/lvm-raid/lvm0`.

```
$ lvdisplay /dev/lvm-raid/lvm0 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/lvm-raid/lvm0
  VG Name                lvm-raid
  LV UUID                FFX673-dGlX-tsEL-6UXl-1hLs-6b3Y-rkO9O2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                223.57 GB
  Current LE             57235
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     0
  Block device           253:2
```